# This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically

Tags: javascript, postgresql

When I use my app and try to change the password, I get this error and I do not know how to solve it

```
@app.route("/changes", methods= ['GET','POST'])
def change():
    user = "Login"
    change_form = forms.ChangeForm(request.form)

    if 'username' in session:
        username = session["username"]
        get = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE cedula = :e", {"e": username}).fetchone()
        user = get.nombre
        actual = get.password
        print (actual)
        if request.method == 'POST' and change_form.validate():
            password = change_form.password.data
            new_password = change_form.new_password.data
            confirm_password = change_form.confirm_password.data
            if password == actual:
                cambio = db.execute("UPDATE users SET password = :new_password WHERE password = :password",{"new_password": confirm_password, "password":actual}).fetchone()
                success_message = 'Cambio Exitoso.'
                flash(success_message)
            else:
                error_message = 'No se pudo cambiar la contraseña.'
                flash(error_message)
        #success_message = '{} Has cambiado tu contraseña!'.format(user)
        #flash(success_message)
        db.commit()

    return render_template('changes.html',form = change_form, user=user)
```

should run normal but I get this error:

> This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

cambio = db.execute("UPDATE users SET password = :new_password WHERE password = :password",{"new_password": confirm_password, "password":actual})**.fetchone()**
This is my error LOL